¿Como dividir un número entero de 32 bits en 4 partes de 8bits?
¿Por qué mi código no me divide bien un número entero de 32 bits? Estoy intentando dividir el número 305419896 en 4 parte de 8bits lo que pasa es que me lo hace mal.
Ayuda por favor.
#include <stdio.h>

/*Declaración de la función printBinary*/
void printBinary(int number, int positions);

void main(){
    /*Declaración de variables globales*/
    int num=0,num1=0,num2=0,num3=0,num4=0; // Guardamos el numero del usuario y los numeros de 8bits
    int test1=0; // Gueardamos el resultado de scanf
    
    /*Entrada*/
    while(test1!=1){
        printf("Ingrese un número entero de 32 bits: ");
        test1=scanf("%i", &num);
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        
        /*Salida de error*/
        if(test1!=1){
            printf("\n[-] Error al introducir los datos.");
        }
    }
    
    /*Descomponer el número de 32 bits en 4 partes de 8 bits*/
    num1 = num & 255;
    num2 = (num >> 8) & 255;
    num3  = (num >> 16) & 255;
    num4= (num >> 24) & 255;

    /*Salida por terminal*/
    printf("Parte 1 (bits 31-24): ");

lo que me da es:

Lo que tiene que dar:


lo que me da es:

Lo que tiene que dar:


Que te da?? y según tu que debería dar?

Bienvenido al sitio, agrega mayor información, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos

No hay nada de malo en el código, excepto que no utilizaste el printf para mostrar los valores,CODIGO

Estas imprimiendo tu salida invertida num1 es el más de la derecha (bits 7-0) el resto está todo OK. En cambio, tu salida esperada tiene mal los valores

No hay forma de obtener el resultado esperado porque no es correcto, esos no son los bits del número decimal 305419896.
00010010 00110100 01010110 01111000 (binario) = 305419896 (decimal)
00010010 00101100 01001101 01101000 (binario) = 304893288 (decimal)

Aunque tu código está cortado, no veo ningún problema. Es de esperarse que obtengas esos bits por el orden en que estás imprimiendo los bytes. No sé cuál será la implementación de la función printBinary, pero veámoslo con un printf de los bytes en hexadecimal:
int num = 0x12345678;

int num1 = num & 255;
int num2 = (num >> 8) & 255;
int num3 = (num >> 16) & 255;
int num4 = (num >> 24) & 255;

printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X", num1, num2, num3, num4);

Imprime:

78 56 34 12

El resultado es correcto, aunque el orden tal vez no sea el que esperabas y la solución es tan simple como cambiar el orden en el que imprimes los números.
printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X", num4, num3, num2, num1);

Para que quede más claro, la operación 0x12345678 & 255 equivale a quedarse con los 8 bits menos significativos (7-0) de 0x12345678 y se calcula de la siguiente manera:
    00010010 00110100 01010110 01111000 (0x12345678)
AND 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 (255)
---------------------------------------
    00000000 00000000 00000000 01111000 (0x78)


Tienes que recorrer todos los 8 bits, bit a bit, de esta manera:
printf("Parte 1 (bits 31-24): ");
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", (num4 >> i) & 1);
}

Al usar & 1, el operador aísla el bit menos significativo después del desplazamiento (>> i), manteniendo solo el bit en la posición 0 y devolviendo 0 o 1.
Para evitar repetir este bucle varias veces, una función simple puede ayudar:
void binarySimples(int num) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) { 
        printf("%d", (num >> i) & 1);
    }
}

Ahora aplicando la función para imprimir:
binarySimples(num4);  // Parte 1 (bits 31-24)
binarySimples(num3);  // Parte 2 (bits 23-16)
binarySimples(num2);  // Parte 3 (bits 15-8)
binarySimples(num1);  // Parte 4 (bits 7-0)

respuesta:
Parte 1 (bits 31-24): 00010010
Parte 2 (bits 23-16): 00110100
Parte 3 (bits 15-8):  01010110
Parte 4 (bits 7-0):   01111000

